# How to use 2 ways data binding in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

I just confuse since I moving from other framework and came from javascript language to angular & typescript to share the data / value between components

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="yourVariable"`: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

Comment: can you drop down the code which you are trying?. we will try to solve it for you

Comment: Go through the angular tutorial, it's worth it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you reach the data using @Input, you can check [this](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/passing-data-angular-2-components-input)

If you want to trigger a function using @Output, you can check [this](https://newbedev.com/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2)

Also, you can use BehavioSubject for streaming data. You can check [this](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc)